# Does Flickr have support for transparant PNG images?

Tags: flickr

I tried uploading a PNG image to Flickr and after being uploaded I copied its link (enlarged version) but the image was JPG thus had no transparency.

I just moved to picasaweb to upload png images but I still want to know if there's any option to upload PNG images or Flickr don't have any support for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flickr don't have support for it. From [their support page](http://www.flickr.com/help/photos/#18) -

> Flickr officially supports JPEGs, non-animated GIFs, and PNGs. You can
>   also upload TIFFs and some other file types, **but they will
>   automatically be converted to and stored in JPEG format.**

Comment: But it says `Flickr officially supports JPEGs, non-animated GIFs, and PNGs. ` which clearly means that it supports JPEGs, non-animated gif and PNG images.

Comment: `but they will automatically be converted to and stored in JPEG format.` Means no transparency.

Comment: Ohh thanks, I didn't noticed it, even you put it in bold. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Pro account, you will have access to the original version of the image, which in the case of a GIF or PNG (but not a TIFF, where the "original" is a converted JPEG, not the actual file you uploaded) will be whatever was uploaded. You could use the link to this original on the external site.

The resized versions (which are all a free account can access) are all JPEGs.